# How to store the xml response that we got from using an api in string?

Tags: java, android

I got the Xml response is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
    <OperationRequest>
        <HTTPHeaders>
            <Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"></Header>
        </HTTPHeaders>
        <RequestId>35529aea-8baf-41f3-85b5-51f9eb434776</RequestId>
        <Arguments>
            <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="AKIAJ3VPWLGL2UIWB3SA"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="projectr0c-21"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="Keywords" Value="iphone"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemSearch"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="ItemAttributes,Images"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="SearchIndex" Value="All"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2018-06-20T05:31:25Z"></Argument>
            <Argument Name="Signature" Value="JIYJVsrpWz0xj3yWS0Pxgnx+PtLpD9bi+jek/hhQwN4="></Argument>
        </Arguments>
        <RequestProcessingTime>0.1281360430000000</RequestProcessingTime>
    </OperationRequest>
    <Items>
        <Request>
            <IsValid>True</IsValid>
            <ItemSearchRequest>
                <Keywords>iphone</Keywords>
                <ResponseGroup>ItemAttributes</ResponseGroup>
                <ResponseGroup>Images</ResponseGroup>
                <SearchIndex>All</SearchIndex>
            </ItemSearchRequest>
        </Request>
        <TotalResults>235263</TotalResults>
        <TotalPages>23527</TotalPages>
        <MoreSearchResultsUrl>https://www.amazon.in/gp/search?linkCode=xm2&amp;SubscriptionId=AKIAJ3VPWLGL2UIWB3SA&amp;keywords=iphone&amp;tag=projectr0c-21&amp;creative=165953&amp;url=search-alias%3Daws-amazon-aps&amp;camp=2025</MoreSearchResultsUrl>
        <Item>
            <ASIN>B06ZXWWD6R</ASIN>
            <ParentASIN>B078ZXDP1N</ParentASIN>
            <DetailPageURL>https://www.amazon.in/Apple-iPhone-SE-Rose-Gold/dp/B06ZXWWD6R?psc=1&amp;SubscriptionId=AKIAJ3VPWLGL2UIWB3SA&amp;tag=projectr0c-21&amp;linkCode=xm2&amp;camp=2025&amp;creative=165953&amp;creativeASIN=B06ZXWWD6R</DetailPageURL>
            <ItemLinks>
                <ItemLink>
                    <Description>Add To Wishlist</Description>
                    <URL>https://www.amazon.in/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html?asin.0=B06ZXWWD6R&amp;SubscriptionId=AKIAJ3VPWLGL2UIWB3SA&amp;tag=projectr0c-21&amp;linkCode=xm2&amp;camp=2025&amp;creative=165953&amp;creativeASIN=B06ZXWWD6R</URL>
                </ItemLink>
                <ItemLink>
                    <Description>Tell A Friend</Description>
                    <URL>https://www.amazon.in/gp/pdp/taf/B06ZXWWD6R?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ3VPWLGL2UIWB3SA&amp;tag=projectr0c-21&amp;linkCode=xm2&amp;camp=2025&amp;creative=165953&amp;creativeASIN=B06ZXWWD6R</URL>
                </ItemLink>
                <ItemLink>
                    <Description>All Customer Reviews</Description>
                    <URL>https://www.amazon.in/review/product/B06ZXWWD6R?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ3VPWLGL2UIWB3SA&amp;tag=projectr0c-21&amp;linkCode=xm2&amp;camp=2025&amp;creative=165953&amp;creativeASIN=B06ZXWWD6R</URL>
                </ItemLink>
                <ItemLink>
                    <Description>All Offers</Description>
                    <URL>https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B06ZXWWD6R?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ3VPWLGL2UIWB3SA&amp;tag=projectr0c-21&amp;linkCode=xm2&amp;camp=2025&amp;creative=165953&amp;creativeASIN=B06ZXWWD6R</URL>
                </ItemLink>
            </ItemLinks>
            <SmallImage>
                <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JpGHacdoL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
                <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
                <Width Units="pixels">37</Width>
            </SmallImage>
            <MediumImage>
                <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JpGHacdoL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
                <Height Units="pixels">160</Height>
                <Width Units="pixels">78</Width>
            </MediumImage>
            <LargeImage>
                <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JpGHacdoL.jpg</URL>
                <Height Units="pixels">500</Height>
                <Width Units="pixels">244</Width>
            </LargeImage>
            <ImageSets>
                <ImageSet Category="variant">
                    <SwatchImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SnU4EOFCL._SL30_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">15</Width>
                    </SwatchImage>
                    <SmallImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SnU4EOFCL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">39</Width>
                    </SmallImage>
                    <ThumbnailImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SnU4EOFCL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">39</Width>
                    </ThumbnailImage>
                    <TinyImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SnU4EOFCL._SL110_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">110</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">57</Width>
                    </TinyImage>
                    <MediumImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SnU4EOFCL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">160</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">82</Width>
                    </MediumImage>
                    <LargeImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SnU4EOFCL.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">500</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">257</Width>
                    </LargeImage>
                </ImageSet>
                <ImageSet Category="variant">
                    <SwatchImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21%2B4L8TqTXL._SL30_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">5</Width>
                    </SwatchImage>
                    <SmallImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21%2B4L8TqTXL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">13</Width>
                    </SmallImage>
                    <ThumbnailImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21%2B4L8TqTXL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">13</Width>
                    </ThumbnailImage>
                    <TinyImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21%2B4L8TqTXL._SL110_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">110</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">19</Width>
                    </TinyImage>
                    <MediumImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21%2B4L8TqTXL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">160</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">27</Width>
                    </MediumImage>
                    <LargeImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/21%2B4L8TqTXL.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">500</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">85</Width>
                    </LargeImage>
                </ImageSet>
                <ImageSet Category="primary">
                    <SwatchImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JpGHacdoL._SL30_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">15</Width>
                    </SwatchImage>
                    <SmallImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JpGHacdoL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">37</Width>
                    </SmallImage>
                    <ThumbnailImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JpGHacdoL._SL75_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">37</Width>
                    </ThumbnailImage>
                    <TinyImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JpGHacdoL._SL110_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">110</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">54</Width>
                    </TinyImage>
                    <MediumImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JpGHacdoL._SL160_.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">160</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">78</Width>
                    </MediumImage>
                    <LargeImage>
                        <URL>https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JpGHacdoL.jpg</URL>
                        <Height Units="pixels">500</Height>
                        <Width Units="pixels">244</Width>
                    </LargeImage>
                </ImageSet>
            </ImageSets>
            <ItemAttributes>
                <Binding>Electronics</Binding>
                <Brand>Apple</Brand>
                <Color>Rose Gold</Color>
                <EAN>0190198293930</EAN>
                <EANList>
                    <EANListElement>0190198293930</EANListElement>
                </EANList>
                <Feature>12MP primary camera with 720p HD video recording, retina flash, ƒ/2.4 aperture, auto HDR for photos, backside illumination sensor, exposure control, improved local tone mapping, face detection, timer mode, burst mode and 1.2MP front facing camera</Feature>
                <Feature>10.16 centimeters (4-inch) LED-backlit multi-touch capacitive touchscreen with 1136 x 640 pixels resolution and 326 ppi pixel density</Feature>
                <Feature>IOS v10 operating system with 1.84GHz A9 Chip 64-bit Architecture Embedded M9 Motion dual core processor, M9 motion GPU, 2GB RAM, 32GB internal memory and single SIM</Feature>
                <Feature>1624mAH lithium-ion battery providing talk-time of 14 hours and standby time of 13 hours</Feature>
                <Feature>1 year manufacturer warranty for device and 6 months manufacturer warranty for in-box accessories including batteries from the date of purchase</Feature>
                <Feature>Audio calling- It supports voice over LTE(VOLTE)</Feature>
                <ItemDimensions>
                    <Height Units="hundredths-inches">232</Height>
                    <Length Units="hundredths-inches">488</Length>
                    <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">25</Weight>
                    <Width Units="hundredths-inches">31</Width>
                </ItemDimensions>
                <Label>Apple Computer</Label>
                <ListPrice>
                    <Amount>2600000</Amount>
                    <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
                    <FormattedPrice>INR 26,000.00</FormattedPrice>
                </ListPrice>
                <Manufacturer>Apple Computer</Manufacturer>
                <Model>iPhone SE</Model>
                <MPN>APE_iPhone SE_ROEGOD_32GB</MPN>
                <OperatingSystem>iOS</OperatingSystem>
                <PackageDimensions>
                    <Height Units="hundredths-inches">236</Height>
                    <Length Units="hundredths-inches">571</Length>
                    <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">90</Weight>
                    <Width Units="hundredths-inches">311</Width>
                </PackageDimensions>
                <PackageQuantity>1</PackageQuantity>
                <PartNumber>APE_iPhone SE_ROEGOD_32GB</PartNumber>
                <ProductGroup>Wireless</ProductGroup>
                <ProductTypeName>PHONE</ProductTypeName>
                <Publisher>Apple Computer</Publisher>
                <ReleaseDate>2017-01-01</ReleaseDate>
                <Size>32GB</Size>
                <Studio>Apple Computer</Studio>
                <Title>Apple iPhone SE (Rose Gold, 32GB)</Title>
                <UPC>190198293930</UPC>
                <UPCList>
                    <UPCListElement>190198293930</UPCListElement>
                </UPCList>
                <Warranty>1 year manufacturer warranty for device and in-box accessories including batteries from the date of purchase</Warranty>
            </ItemAttributes>
        </Item>
```

How to this response store in string for pass value into the json object

Answer (score 0):

***Firstly Create a model and then Deserialize this XML to Model
And From that object, you will get your values Again serialize that object into JSON or on any type based on your need***

```
public class Codebeautify {
 ItemSearchResponse ItemSearchResponseObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public ItemSearchResponse getItemSearchResponse() {
  return ItemSearchResponseObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setItemSearchResponse(ItemSearchResponse ItemSearchResponseObject) {
  this.ItemSearchResponseObject = ItemSearchResponseObject;
 }
}
public class ItemSearchResponse {
 Parsererror ParsererrorObject;
 OperationRequest OperationRequestObject;
 Items ItemsObject;
 private String _xmlns;


 // Getter Methods 

 public Parsererror getParsererror() {
  return ParsererrorObject;
 }

 public OperationRequest getOperationRequest() {
  return OperationRequestObject;
 }

 public Items getItems() {
  return ItemsObject;
 }

 public String get_xmlns() {
  return _xmlns;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setParsererror(Parsererror parsererrorObject) {
  this.ParsererrorObject = parsererrorObject;
 }

 public void setOperationRequest(OperationRequest OperationRequestObject) {
  this.OperationRequestObject = OperationRequestObject;
 }

 public void setItems(Items ItemsObject) {
  this.ItemsObject = ItemsObject;
 }

 public void set_xmlns(String _xmlns) {
  this._xmlns = _xmlns;
 }
}
public class Items {
 Request RequestObject;
 private String TotalResults;
 private String TotalPages;
 private String MoreSearchResultsUrl;
 Item ItemObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public Request getRequest() {
  return RequestObject;
 }

 public String getTotalResults() {
  return TotalResults;
 }

 public String getTotalPages() {
  return TotalPages;
 }

 public String getMoreSearchResultsUrl() {
  return MoreSearchResultsUrl;
 }

 public Item getItem() {
  return ItemObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setRequest(Request RequestObject) {
  this.RequestObject = RequestObject;
 }

 public void setTotalResults(String TotalResults) {
  this.TotalResults = TotalResults;
 }

 public void setTotalPages(String TotalPages) {
  this.TotalPages = TotalPages;
 }

 public void setMoreSearchResultsUrl(String MoreSearchResultsUrl) {
  this.MoreSearchResultsUrl = MoreSearchResultsUrl;
 }

 public void setItem(Item ItemObject) {
  this.ItemObject = ItemObject;
 }
}
public class Item {
 private String ASIN;
 private String ParentASIN;
 private String DetailPageURL;
 ItemLinks ItemLinksObject;
 SmallImage SmallImageObject;
 MediumImage MediumImageObject;
 LargeImage LargeImageObject;
 ImageSets ImageSetsObject;
 ItemAttributes ItemAttributesObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getASIN() {
  return ASIN;
 }

 public String getParentASIN() {
  return ParentASIN;
 }

 public String getDetailPageURL() {
  return DetailPageURL;
 }

 public ItemLinks getItemLinks() {
  return ItemLinksObject;
 }

 public SmallImage getSmallImage() {
  return SmallImageObject;
 }

 public MediumImage getMediumImage() {
  return MediumImageObject;
 }

 public LargeImage getLargeImage() {
  return LargeImageObject;
 }

 public ImageSets getImageSets() {
  return ImageSetsObject;
 }

 public ItemAttributes getItemAttributes() {
  return ItemAttributesObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setASIN(String ASIN) {
  this.ASIN = ASIN;
 }

 public void setParentASIN(String ParentASIN) {
  this.ParentASIN = ParentASIN;
 }

 public void setDetailPageURL(String DetailPageURL) {
  this.DetailPageURL = DetailPageURL;
 }

 public void setItemLinks(ItemLinks ItemLinksObject) {
  this.ItemLinksObject = ItemLinksObject;
 }

 public void setSmallImage(SmallImage SmallImageObject) {
  this.SmallImageObject = SmallImageObject;
 }

 public void setMediumImage(MediumImage MediumImageObject) {
  this.MediumImageObject = MediumImageObject;
 }

 public void setLargeImage(LargeImage LargeImageObject) {
  this.LargeImageObject = LargeImageObject;
 }

 public void setImageSets(ImageSets ImageSetsObject) {
  this.ImageSetsObject = ImageSetsObject;
 }

 public void setItemAttributes(ItemAttributes ItemAttributesObject) {
  this.ItemAttributesObject = ItemAttributesObject;
 }
}
public class ItemAttributes {
 private String Binding;
 private String Brand;
 private String Color;
 private String EAN;
 EANList EANListObject;
 ArrayList < Object > Feature = new ArrayList < Object > ();
 ItemDimensions ItemDimensionsObject;
 private String Label;
 ListPrice ListPriceObject;
 private String Manufacturer;
 private String Model;
 private String MPN;
 private String OperatingSystem;
 PackageDimensions PackageDimensionsObject;
 private String PackageQuantity;
 private String PartNumber;
 private String ProductGroup;
 private String ProductTypeName;
 private String Publisher;
 private String ReleaseDate;
 private String Size;
 private String Studio;
 private String Title;
 private String UPC;
 UPCList UPCListObject;
 private String Warranty;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getBinding() {
  return Binding;
 }

 public String getBrand() {
  return Brand;
 }

 public String getColor() {
  return Color;
 }

 public String getEAN() {
  return EAN;
 }

 public EANList getEANList() {
  return EANListObject;
 }

 public ItemDimensions getItemDimensions() {
  return ItemDimensionsObject;
 }

 public String getLabel() {
  return Label;
 }

 public ListPrice getListPrice() {
  return ListPriceObject;
 }

 public String getManufacturer() {
  return Manufacturer;
 }

 public String getModel() {
  return Model;
 }

 public String getMPN() {
  return MPN;
 }

 public String getOperatingSystem() {
  return OperatingSystem;
 }

 public PackageDimensions getPackageDimensions() {
  return PackageDimensionsObject;
 }

 public String getPackageQuantity() {
  return PackageQuantity;
 }

 public String getPartNumber() {
  return PartNumber;
 }

 public String getProductGroup() {
  return ProductGroup;
 }

 public String getProductTypeName() {
  return ProductTypeName;
 }

 public String getPublisher() {
  return Publisher;
 }

 public String getReleaseDate() {
  return ReleaseDate;
 }

 public String getSize() {
  return Size;
 }

 public String getStudio() {
  return Studio;
 }

 public String getTitle() {
  return Title;
 }

 public String getUPC() {
  return UPC;
 }

 public UPCList getUPCList() {
  return UPCListObject;
 }

 public String getWarranty() {
  return Warranty;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setBinding(String Binding) {
  this.Binding = Binding;
 }

 public void setBrand(String Brand) {
  this.Brand = Brand;
 }

 public void setColor(String Color) {
  this.Color = Color;
 }

 public void setEAN(String EAN) {
  this.EAN = EAN;
 }

 public void setEANList(EANList EANListObject) {
  this.EANListObject = EANListObject;
 }

 public void setItemDimensions(ItemDimensions ItemDimensionsObject) {
  this.ItemDimensionsObject = ItemDimensionsObject;
 }

 public void setLabel(String Label) {
  this.Label = Label;
 }

 public void setListPrice(ListPrice ListPriceObject) {
  this.ListPriceObject = ListPriceObject;
 }

 public void setManufacturer(String Manufacturer) {
  this.Manufacturer = Manufacturer;
 }

 public void setModel(String Model) {
  this.Model = Model;
 }

 public void setMPN(String MPN) {
  this.MPN = MPN;
 }

 public void setOperatingSystem(String OperatingSystem) {
  this.OperatingSystem = OperatingSystem;
 }

 public void setPackageDimensions(PackageDimensions PackageDimensionsObject) {
  this.PackageDimensionsObject = PackageDimensionsObject;
 }

 public void setPackageQuantity(String PackageQuantity) {
  this.PackageQuantity = PackageQuantity;
 }

 public void setPartNumber(String PartNumber) {
  this.PartNumber = PartNumber;
 }

 public void setProductGroup(String ProductGroup) {
  this.ProductGroup = ProductGroup;
 }

 public void setProductTypeName(String ProductTypeName) {
  this.ProductTypeName = ProductTypeName;
 }

 public void setPublisher(String Publisher) {
  this.Publisher = Publisher;
 }

 public void setReleaseDate(String ReleaseDate) {
  this.ReleaseDate = ReleaseDate;
 }

 public void setSize(String Size) {
  this.Size = Size;
 }

 public void setStudio(String Studio) {
  this.Studio = Studio;
 }

 public void setTitle(String Title) {
  this.Title = Title;
 }

 public void setUPC(String UPC) {
  this.UPC = UPC;
 }

 public void setUPCList(UPCList UPCListObject) {
  this.UPCListObject = UPCListObject;
 }

 public void setWarranty(String Warranty) {
  this.Warranty = Warranty;
 }
}
public class UPCList {
 private String UPCListElement;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getUPCListElement() {
  return UPCListElement;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setUPCListElement(String UPCListElement) {
  this.UPCListElement = UPCListElement;
 }
}
public class PackageDimensions {
 Height HeightObject;
 Length LengthObject;
 Weight WeightObject;
 Width WidthObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public Height getHeight() {
  return HeightObject;
 }

 public Length getLength() {
  return LengthObject;
 }

 public Weight getWeight() {
  return WeightObject;
 }

 public Width getWidth() {
  return WidthObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setHeight(Height HeightObject) {
  this.HeightObject = HeightObject;
 }

 public void setLength(Length LengthObject) {
  this.LengthObject = LengthObject;
 }

 public void setWeight(Weight WeightObject) {
  this.WeightObject = WeightObject;
 }

 public void setWidth(Width WidthObject) {
  this.WidthObject = WidthObject;
 }
}
public class Width {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class Weight {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class Length {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class Height {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class ListPrice {
 private String Amount;
 private String CurrencyCode;
 private String FormattedPrice;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getAmount() {
  return Amount;
 }

 public String getCurrencyCode() {
  return CurrencyCode;
 }

 public String getFormattedPrice() {
  return FormattedPrice;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setAmount(String Amount) {
  this.Amount = Amount;
 }

 public void setCurrencyCode(String CurrencyCode) {
  this.CurrencyCode = CurrencyCode;
 }

 public void setFormattedPrice(String FormattedPrice) {
  this.FormattedPrice = FormattedPrice;
 }
}
public class ItemDimensions {
 Height HeightObject;
 Length LengthObject;
 Weight WeightObject;
 Width WidthObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public Height getHeight() {
  return HeightObject;
 }

 public Length getLength() {
  return LengthObject;
 }

 public Weight getWeight() {
  return WeightObject;
 }

 public Width getWidth() {
  return WidthObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setHeight(Height HeightObject) {
  this.HeightObject = HeightObject;
 }

 public void setLength(Length LengthObject) {
  this.LengthObject = LengthObject;
 }

 public void setWeight(Weight WeightObject) {
  this.WeightObject = WeightObject;
 }

 public void setWidth(Width WidthObject) {
  this.WidthObject = WidthObject;
 }
}
public class Width {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class Weight {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class Length {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class Height {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class EANList {
 private String EANListElement;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getEANListElement() {
  return EANListElement;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setEANListElement(String EANListElement) {
  this.EANListElement = EANListElement;
 }
}
public class ImageSets {
 ArrayList < Object > ImageSet = new ArrayList < Object > ();


 // Getter Methods 



 // Setter Methods 


}
public class LargeImage {
 private String URL;
 Height HeightObject;
 Width WidthObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getURL() {
  return URL;
 }

 public Height getHeight() {
  return HeightObject;
 }

 public Width getWidth() {
  return WidthObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setURL(String URL) {
  this.URL = URL;
 }

 public void setHeight(Height HeightObject) {
  this.HeightObject = HeightObject;
 }

 public void setWidth(Width WidthObject) {
  this.WidthObject = WidthObject;
 }
}
public class Width {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class Height {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class MediumImage {
 private String URL;
 Height HeightObject;
 Width WidthObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getURL() {
  return URL;
 }

 public Height getHeight() {
  return HeightObject;
 }

 public Width getWidth() {
  return WidthObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setURL(String URL) {
  this.URL = URL;
 }

 public void setHeight(Height HeightObject) {
  this.HeightObject = HeightObject;
 }

 public void setWidth(Width WidthObject) {
  this.WidthObject = WidthObject;
 }
}
public class Width {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class Height {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class SmallImage {
 private String URL;
 Height HeightObject;
 Width WidthObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getURL() {
  return URL;
 }

 public Height getHeight() {
  return HeightObject;
 }

 public Width getWidth() {
  return WidthObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setURL(String URL) {
  this.URL = URL;
 }

 public void setHeight(Height HeightObject) {
  this.HeightObject = HeightObject;
 }

 public void setWidth(Width WidthObject) {
  this.WidthObject = WidthObject;
 }
}
public class Width {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class Height {
 private String _Units;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Units() {
  return _Units;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Units(String _Units) {
  this._Units = _Units;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
public class ItemLinks {
 ArrayList < Object > ItemLink = new ArrayList < Object > ();


 // Getter Methods 



 // Setter Methods 


}
public class Request {
 private String IsValid;
 ItemSearchRequest ItemSearchRequestObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getIsValid() {
  return IsValid;
 }

 public ItemSearchRequest getItemSearchRequest() {
  return ItemSearchRequestObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setIsValid(String IsValid) {
  this.IsValid = IsValid;
 }

 public void setItemSearchRequest(ItemSearchRequest ItemSearchRequestObject) {
  this.ItemSearchRequestObject = ItemSearchRequestObject;
 }
}
public class ItemSearchRequest {
 private String Keywords;
 ArrayList < Object > ResponseGroup = new ArrayList < Object > ();
 private String SearchIndex;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getKeywords() {
  return Keywords;
 }

 public String getSearchIndex() {
  return SearchIndex;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setKeywords(String Keywords) {
  this.Keywords = Keywords;
 }

 public void setSearchIndex(String SearchIndex) {
  this.SearchIndex = SearchIndex;
 }
}
public class OperationRequest {
 HTTPHeaders HTTPHeadersObject;
 private String RequestId;
 Arguments ArgumentsObject;
 private String RequestProcessingTime;


 // Getter Methods 

 public HTTPHeaders getHTTPHeaders() {
  return HTTPHeadersObject;
 }

 public String getRequestId() {
  return RequestId;
 }

 public Arguments getArguments() {
  return ArgumentsObject;
 }

 public String getRequestProcessingTime() {
  return RequestProcessingTime;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setHTTPHeaders(HTTPHeaders HTTPHeadersObject) {
  this.HTTPHeadersObject = HTTPHeadersObject;
 }

 public void setRequestId(String RequestId) {
  this.RequestId = RequestId;
 }

 public void setArguments(Arguments ArgumentsObject) {
  this.ArgumentsObject = ArgumentsObject;
 }

 public void setRequestProcessingTime(String RequestProcessingTime) {
  this.RequestProcessingTime = RequestProcessingTime;
 }
}
public class Arguments {
 ArrayList < Object > Argument = new ArrayList < Object > ();


 // Getter Methods 



 // Setter Methods 


}
public class HTTPHeaders {
 Header HeaderObject;


 // Getter Methods 

 public Header getHeader() {
  return HeaderObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setHeader(Header HeaderObject) {
  this.HeaderObject = HeaderObject;
 }
}
public class Header {
 private String _Name;
 private String _Value;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_Name() {
  return _Name;
 }

 public String get_Value() {
  return _Value;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_Name(String _Name) {
  this._Name = _Name;
 }

 public void set_Value(String _Value) {
  this._Value = _Value;
 }
}
public class Parsererror {
 ArrayList < Object > h3 = new ArrayList < Object > ();
 Div DivObject;
 private String _style;


 // Getter Methods 

 public Div getDiv() {
  return DivObject;
 }

 public String get_style() {
  return _style;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setDiv(Div divObject) {
  this.DivObject = divObject;
 }

 public void set_style(String _style) {
  this._style = _style;
 }
}
public class Div {
 private String _style;
 private String __text;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get_style() {
  return _style;
 }

 public String get__text() {
  return __text;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void set_style(String _style) {
  this._style = _style;
 }

 public void set__text(String __text) {
  this.__text = __text;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can please tell me how to use this mode classes in project?

Comment: Create new java file give it a name that's it and perform deserialization @poojitha

Comment: First Create New class and copy paste this model first  and in Activity created an object and deserialized it that's it if it's still not work tell me @poojitha

Comment: Can u please tell me how to pass below url in async task in android                                 http://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ3VPWLAjHHJGL2UIWB3SA&AssociateTag=projectr0c-21&Keywords=tv&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2CImages&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2018-06-21T04%3A09%3A39Z&Signature=MsyeR325yT0%2BTLwnruzP5jX5wySxuvH9mFPsKq%2Bt0%2BQ%3D

Comment: Dont use async task try volley call instead

Comment: I was used volley but stringRequest function does't call

Comment: Ohk.i will help you through team viewer or by email the code first send me your code and then i will add code and then send back to you